# How to set a session variable in a HTML template in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to set value to Django session within the template and then posible used in the view.

I'm doing something like this

```
{% block body %}
    <html>
     {%  request.session.fav_color="red"  %}

    <div> Is your favorite color {{ request.session.fav_color}} ?</div>

  </html>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why this may not be a good idea:

- Templates should deal with presentation only. If you are placing logic in the template it is supposed to be presentation logic. Placing business logic in the template is a violation of the SoC (separation of concerns).
- Rendering the template often is one of the last things you do in a view so it is hard to get the cat back in the bag if you have already sent the data to the browser (and if you rendered the template but haven't sent data down the pipe you can just update the value in the view instead of trying to do it in the template).

If you are interacting with the user the traditional way to do it is using a form (even if it is a form with only the submit button) - or posting data to the server in the frontend using AJAX.